# Subject of a sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

**the number of passengers in cruise ships is also soaring**

Why is the verb used here 'is' ? 
I thought number of passengers is plural and the verb used should be 'are' ?

Pls help.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

"the number of passengers in cruise ships *is* also soaring."

Because the word *number* is singular, when used in the context of "The number of".